# Example of conservative vector field that is not irrotational

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Can anyone suggest an example of a vector field $F: A \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfies all the following conditions?

- $F$ does not belong to $C^1(A)$
- $F$ is conservative in $A$
- It is not true that $\mathrm{curl} F(x)=\bar{0}$ $\,\,\,\,\forall x \in A$

(Also an example in dimensions other than $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be good)

Comment: You want a function that _isn't_ continuously differentiable on $A$?

Comment: @anomaly Yes (first condition), otherwise there is a theorem that states that such vector field cannot exist

Comment: RIght, that's what I thought you were asking about (or about the well-known counterexamples to the converse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we give an example in $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
Generalizing to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is straightforward. 
Let 
$$\varphi = \begin{cases}
\frac{x y(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}, & (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\
0, & \textrm{else}
\end{cases}$$
and consider the gradient field ${\bf F}=\nabla\varphi$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$. 
It is a standard exercise to show that $\mathrm{curl}\,{\bf F}$ is undefined at the origin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I may ask, here $A= \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{\bar{0} \}$, so actually I think $\mathrm{curl} {\bf F}$ is non zero (actually non defined) only in a point that does not belong to $A$, while in question it is stated that $\mathrm{curl} {\bf F}$ should be nonzero (or not defined) in a point of $A$.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah yes, we define $\varphi(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for what you added! I tried to calculate $\mathrm{curl} {\bf F}$ but I do get zero everywhere. Here is what I get: 
$${\bf F}=(F_1,F_2)= \begin{cases}
\bigg( \frac{y \left(x^4+4 x^2 y^2-y^4\right)}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} , \frac{x^5-4 x^3 y^2-x y^4}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2} \bigg )& (x,y)\ne (0,0) \\
0 & \textrm{else}
\end{cases}$$
The $\mathrm{curl} {\bf F}$ is zero away from the origin, but also there, since $$\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}(0,0)=\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}(0,0)=0$$
I checked with mathematica and I get these results.. Did I make any mistakes?

Comment: @Gianolepo: I find $\varphi_{y}|_{(x,0)} = x$, so $\varphi_{yx}|_{(0,0)}=1$. Also $\varphi_{x}|_{(0,y)} = x$, so $\varphi_{xy}|_{(0,0)}=-1$.

Comment: @user26872 You meant $\varphi_x|_{(0,y)} = -y$.

Comment: @JoãoJúnior: Thank you for correcting this old typo, João!

Answer (score 1):

The field $F$ is conservative, so it has antiderivative: we have $F=\mathrm{grad}\,\varphi$ with some scalar field $\varphi$. If $F$ is differentiable at some point $a$, then $\mathrm{curl}\,F(a)=0$ by Young's theorem. Therefore, curl is either zero or undefined.

An example for undefined curl is:
$$
F(x,y,z,\ldots) = \big(|x|,0,0,\ldots\big).
$$
This field has the antiderivative $\frac{x|x|}{2}$ so it is conservative; but 
$\mathrm{curl}\,F$ is undefined along the plane $x=0$.

If you want to define curl using only partial derivatives (although curl should be independent from the co-ordinate system), a modified construction is
$$
F = \mathrm{grad} \frac{(x+y)|x+y|}2 = \big( |x+y|,|x+y|, 0 \big).
$$